# Conditional redirect based on referrer

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Is it possible to conditionally redirect based on the referrer of the visitor?

What I want to do is redirecting the user if it comes from a specific domain (and/or any other subdomains), if there is no referrer or the domain does not match, no redirection should apply.

I was thinking using getServerSideProps().

Answer (score 1):

Such logic reading headers needs to be on *some* server and you should be able to read the referrer in the [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) where you can handle redirects too. This should work in theory:

```
// pages/_middleware.ts
import type { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  console.log('referrer', req.referrer); // do your domain parsing / regex here

  // redirect with NextResponse.redirect()
}
```

There are inherent limits in reliability of the referrer as the value might be [opaque](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noreferrer) to you.

I'd question the use case of such source sniffing and conditional redirects in first place.